# using Accordion, Jquery ,will it affect SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, blackhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

I am planning to use Accrodion and Jquery in My website. previously to animate the contents in the website i used Flash but content (text ) in the flash are not indexable in the search engine

and since major contents of my site comes with in animated Tab using Accordion and J query and most of the text are hidden in DIV so i want to know whether this will effect the SEO.

Because most of the contents are hidden initially by default and by definition of Black hat Seo,this sounds similar to black hat SEO ...

will google treat my site same as Black hat SEO or Is using Accordion in website is acceptable in SEO ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a *lot* more involved in being considered "black hat" than just having some–temporarily–hidden divs on your pages. The text will still be accessible to search engines for indexing(assuming you're not using Ajax loading), and there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think for some reasons that it cannot be considered as black hat. When a robot parses your website it actually reads your code and records the direct accessible information it needs (No Ajax load methods). Another reason is since Google is also using JQuery i think everyone can use that with no worry about SEO.

BUT, cuz their is a but :)! this doesn't mean you should be tricky and try to fool the robot by adding tons of non necessary contents in order to have a better SEO. I am sure robots are perfectly able to see that. I actually think that this goes for everything no matter which language you use. You should just code as fair as possible avoiding tricky methods and respect basic SEO rules in order to, HOPEFULLY, have a good SEO.