# Official Google 10 minutes SEO video and page related terms

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

According to [this](http://mashable.com/2012/06/26/google-seo-tips/) link, one should add some terms related to the page content. I am adding the text like:

`<div style="display:none">term1 term2 term3 term4 term5</div>`

**My questions:** Does it affect the SEO for my website if I am not displaying the terms on page? (I am using `display:none`). In other words, the page related terms are in source code but not being displayed.