# Will using this CSS solution for Facebook Page Follow plugin violate search engine guidelines?

Tags: seo, google, css, hidden-text

I encountered a problem with the Facebook Page Follow plugin on my website where the plugin would disappear when I rotated my device (changing orientation), despite initially appearing correctly. To fix this issue, I attempted a solution using CSS, which appears to have worked. Will this approach violate any search engine guidelines?

```
.fb-page{
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait){
    .fb-page{
        display:block
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape){
    .fb-page{
        display:block
    }
}
```

Comment: What guidelines are you worried about violating?

Comment: Are you missing a `.` in front of the first `fb-page`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, there should be a . in front of fb-page. I am worried the remote possibility that  crawlers can think I am wilfully hiding some content. Sorry, I know my worry is far fetched. But just checking before implementing on my live website which is ranking reasonably well.

Comment: Maybe this would answer your question: [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)